# How to pass multiple parameter in Spring 3.0 AOP Advice method (@Before) using annotation?

Tags: spring-aop

I am preparing Spring AOP Demo Application.I am stuck.
My query is ..
How to pass multiple parameter in Spring 3.0 AOP Advice method (@Before) using annotation ?

Answer (score 2):

from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html check section 6.2.4.6.2

You can pass parameters following way

```
@Before("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation() &&" + 
        "args(account,..)")
public void validateAccount(Account account) {
  // ...
}
```